# 2 countries name into 1 country name

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

Below I operate two countries name into a country name.
The 3 countries must have different names.
Determine how the operation works, then replace ?? with a country name.

**Example**
australia # poland = austria
romania # brazil = oman
romania # moldova = iran
lithuania # venezuela = haiti
sierra leone # montenegro = israel
mongolia # congo = mali

**Question**
malawi # norway = ??
nigeria # belgium = ??
argentina # botswana = ??
somalia # vietnam = ??

**Bonus puzzle**
Find another set of 2 countries to which the operation can be applied plus its resulting country name.

Comment: IMO you only need one example. The rest could have been questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The operation #...

> Removes the letters in the second country from the first country name, then anagrams the remaining letters. You remove only as many of a specific letter as the number of times it appears in the second country's name.

Operation results:

> malawi # norway = **mali**
>  nigeria # belgium = **iran**
>  argentina # botswana = **niger**
>  somalia # vietnam = **laos**

Bonus question:

> dominica # morocco = india

Comment: woww... so fast.

Comment: @rybo111 I agree that it's not perfectly explained, so I tried to change the wording. Feel free to suggest something better if you have any idea!

Comment: Looks good now, can't think of a better way to summarise than you have.